# Why isn't this angular expression working in Plunker? {{ 843 / 42 }}

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm learning Angular on Plural Sight and the first lesson gives an example of how to use the ng-app directive.

Here's a link to the Plunker editor
http://plnkr.co/edit/HIDCS8A9CR1jnAIDR0Zb?p=preview

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="2.0.0" 
            src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-snapshot/angular2.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app>
    <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
    {{ 843 /42 }}
  </body>
</html>
```

The example that was given uses the expression {{ 843 / 42 }} to demonstrate how angular would render the quotient on a webpage.

I've copied the lesson script several times over and can't figure out what I'm doing wrong and why its rendering as text.

This is my first post on stackoverflow, and I'm happy to join the community!

Thanks Again. 
Shamus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks so much for your answers! I was able to figure out that when plunker adds the angular package, the default url is pointing to Angular 2.x. instead of 1.x as mentioned by "developer033" I went to the angular site and directly borrowed the CDN link from their setup page:

https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js

And now it seems to work just fine. When you're getting started its always a bit frustrating when you spend the most time on the tiniest issues, but I'm glad I found stackoverflow to eliminate most of that guess work.

Thanks again!

Shamus

Comment: The cause is that you were trying to use `Angular 2.x` instead of 1.x..

Comment: Would you say 2.x is very different from 1.x? Does it follow new conventions?

Answer (score 0):

Your Angular is throwing an error when its running.

You need to import the system library.

[image: Check out the dev console]
See in the dev console.

Checkout [this link](https://github.com/angular/quickstart/issues/25) to get yourself setup